# Find records with join matching all join IDs

Tags: mariadb, join, query, mariadb-10.5

Suppose to have the following database setup:

```
Users (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(255)
)

OrgUnits (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(255)
)

Users_OrgUnits (
  user_id int,
  orgunit_id int,
  primary key (user_id, orgunit_id)
)
```

You could easily find all users belonging to a certain OU with a query like

```
SELECT U.*
FROM Users U
JOIN Users_OrgUnits UOU ON (
  U.user_id = UOU.user_id
  AND UOU.orgunit_id = X
)
```

Is there a way, **with a single query**, to ask the database for all users belonging to two or more OUs **at the same time**?

If you do something like

```
SELECT U.*
FROM Users U
JOIN Users_OrgUnits UOU ON (
  U.user_id = UOU.user_id
  AND UOU.orgunit_id IN (X, Y)
)
```

You'd get users belonging to at least one of those UOs, not necessarily both of them.

EXAMPLE:

**Users**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | admin |
| 2 | user1 |
| 3 | user2 |
| 4 | user3 |

**OrgUnits**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Administration |
| 2 | HR |
| 3 | Payroll |
| 4 | Health & Safety |

**Users_OrgUnits**

| user_id | orgunit_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

Now, I would like to ask for all users belonging to both "Payroll" and "Health & Safety", that is, OUs with ID 3 and 4, and get this result:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | user2 |
| 4 | user3 |

Comment: @ErgestBasha example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by a simple having count clause:

> I would like to ask for all users belonging to both "Payroll" and
> "Health & Safety", that is, OUs with ID 3 and 4

```
select u.id,u.name
from Users u 
inner join Users_OrgUnits uou on uou.user_id=u.id
inner join OrgUnits uo on uo.id=uou.orgunit_id
where uo.name in ('Payroll','Health & Safety')
group by u.id,u.name
having count(distinct uo.name) >1;
```

or written differently using the id

```
select u.id,u.name
from Users u 
inner join Users_OrgUnits uou on uou.user_id=u.id
inner join OrgUnits uo on uo.id=uou.orgunit_id
where uo.id in (3,4)
group by u.id,u.name
having count(distinct uo.id) >1;.
```

> Is there a way, with a single query, to ask the database for all users
> belonging to two or more OUs at the same time?

```
select u.id,u.name
from Users u 
inner join Users_OrgUnits uou on uou.user_id=u.id
inner join OrgUnits uo on uo.id=uou.orgunit_id
group by u.id,u.name
having count(distinct orgunit_id) >1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=e1d7a2db24595a21c3b18f08f7f0adb6

`having count(distinct orgunit_id) >1;` will return only the values repeated more than once 2,3,... for each `user_id` on `Users_OrgUnits` table

Comment: That seems what I was looking for, thanks; I'm going to try that out and see if it works.